# Problem with Reinforcement Learning Algorithm in AWS Sagemaker using custom Docker Image

Tags: docker, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, reinforcement-learning

I am not using any of the recommended algorithms in the AWS Sagemaker Examples. My question is simply understanding whether this error occurs because of the way I create docker image.

I use MacBook Pro M1 to create the Docker image, and I am launching in a ml.m5.xlarge instance. (First I want to know if this is the problem).
I want to also mention that my algorithm is a bit weird; in the sense I it is raw RL job. Not optimised with Ray or StableBaselines, so when I try to use RLEstimator in Sagemaker instead of Estimator class I wasn't able to execute the training. However, I do not believe this error is due to that problem. Hoping to get some insight from anyone who has experience in AWS Sagemaker, Docker.

[image: AWS Sagemaker Error]